# html transition text doesn't work

Tags: css, html

So, I have an image and I need to slide text on that image from right side. I haven't really worked with transitions. And also I need that to be automatically when refreshing the page, is it possible without js ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>banner</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #container {
        width:600px;
    }
    h1{
        color: #aaba38;
        font-size: 26px;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    #slide{
        position: relative;
        right: 0px;
         -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    }   
    #slide:hover{
        position: relative;
        right: 120px;
         -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
       transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="image">
            <img src="html-5-1.jpg" alt="image_1" width="300" height="250" style="display: block; float:left;" />
        </div>
        <div id="slide">
            <h1>Text to slide left</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `all` there, not `color`:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: ok, nice. And isit posible to start this without hovering, just after refresh ?

Comment: @eriks yes, but you will need to use animation and keyframes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes